# php host no redirecting properly on LAN

Tags: php, redirect, localhost

i have this piece of code, saved inside a file called 'functions.php'

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$folder = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\'); 

function redirect_to_home(){    /*function to redirect the user ot his profile page, or       admin page if he is an administrator*/
if(admin_class::isadmin()){    
header("Location:http://$host$folder//adminindex.php"); 
exit();
}
 else{
 header("Location:http://$host$folder/profile.php");
 exit();
 }     
}

function redirect_to_welcome(){
header("Location:http://$host$folder/index.php");
exit;
}

function redirect_to_loan(){
header("Location:http://$host$folder/loan.php");
exit;
}
```

When browsing through the website itself, these don't work correctly and I could only navigate via  links within the website, I've finished the whole thing though (I just used header("Location:http://`localhost`/YMMLS//pagename.php") when I was developing).

And I need some enlightenment here, I'm launching this website via LAN and those connected could access it via xxx.xxx.xxx.x/YMMLS. But of course, the website fails to redirect properly when any of these functions are called.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried using your `local IP` instead `localhost`?

Comment: Additional Comment, NetBeans 7.2.1 shows a warning in the code lines containing the $host and $folder variables, it marks them as 'unused' from declaration and 'seems to be uninitialized' when used, although they are in the SAME file. blows up my mind

Comment: @JamieAnacleto its ok netbeans show it to you because  $_SERVER['some key'] values are not explicitly initialized in your code

Comment: Why dont you try adding a back slash between $host and $folder 
Like:
     header("Location:http://$host/$folder/profile.php");

or use a "." between them

Comment: what do you mean by these don't work correctly.... are they redirecting to undersired path .. or not rediecting anywhere .. ?

Comment: @JamieAnacleto instead of "Location:http://$host$folder/index.php" try to use "Location:http://{$host}{$folder}/index.php"

Comment: @legendinmaking

it doesnt seem to work, Xampp shows up and shows a warning message, but i dont think that even if it did work, it would be effective, since I'm not a fan of static IP addressing.

Comment: @new_developer

when these are invoked, the URL bar on Chrome just shows plain index.php after I Login, of course, that page does not exist

Comment: Where do your $host and $folder variables come from ? They may need to be declared as global in each function. Have you checked what they contain ?

Comment: @JamieAnacleto what kind of debugging have you did so far .. ?

Comment: @JamieAnacleto wldsvc is right ...... I didnt notived that before .. you have to use them as global variable .. see my answer..

Comment: `function redirect_to_loan(){
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$folder = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\'); 
header("Location: http://$host$folder/loan.php");
exit;
}` this piece of code works

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is warning you, because the variables are declared *outside* the function.
They don't exist within the scope of the function.  Sure, you can call the function -- from outside the function, where those variables *do* exist -- but that's different. :)

Here -- try this;

```
class redirect {

    public $host = '';
    public $folder = '';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $this->folder = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\');
    }

    public function home() {    /*function to redirect the user ot his profile page, or admin page if he is an administrator*/
        if(admin_class::isadmin()){
            header("Location: http://$host$folder/adminindex.php");
        } else {
            header("Location: http://$host$folder/profile.php");
        }
        exit();
    }

    public function welcome() {
        header("Location: http://$host$folder/index.php");
        exit;
    }

    public function loan() {
        header("Location: http://$host$folder/loan.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Instead of calling simply `redirect_to_home();` this would be invoked by `redirect::home();`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$folder = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\'); 

function redirect_to_home(){  

 global $host, $folder;    

if(admin_class::isadmin()){    
  header("Location:http://$host$folder//adminindex.php"); 
  exit();
 }
 else{
 header("Location:http://$host$folder/profile.php");
exit();
}     
}
```

If this works then change this in all other functions
GOOD LUCK!!

DOCUMENTATION http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: This seems to have solved it, by im also trying your solutions :)


function head($page){
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $folder = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\'); 
    header ("Location:http://$host$folder/$page.php");
}

Comment: @JamieAnacleto your solution is also right but in that case you have declare $host and $folder in every function